# AWS | Athena | Boto3 - Retrieve all execution details of a query with name or ID

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, boto3, amazon-athena

I went through the whole boto3 documentation and it seems like there is no way to retrieve the execution details of a **specific** query. The only way that I can see is to get the execution IDs of all queries by using `list_query_executions()` and then use either `get_query_execution()` or `batch_get_query_execution()`. However, even in the execution details there is no field that allows you to map the executions to a specific query (you can use the query string, but this is not favorable, as the query string is subject to change). In that sense, I can only see the option to get all execution details... but no way to map them to a query (e.g. by using the query ID or name)

Do I miss something here? Is it somehow possible to cleanly map a query to all of its executions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Even this being an old post I thought it shouldn't go unanswered.

There's no way of uniquely identifying a query execution in Athena other than its QueryExecutionId. If you run the same query multiple times its execution will yield different ids every time, even if the QueryString is the same every time.
The only way to map a specific query string count, to the best of my knowledge, is in fact parsing through the QueryString as you yourself stated. If the QueryString is changed it is in fact a different query, so I don't get your point on saying that different QueryString may still be mapped to the same query.

'Select * from fruits_table where name = "banana" and taste_category = "sweet"'
and
'Select * from fruits_table where taste_category = "sweet" and name = "banana"'

Are in fact different queries, even though they return same results.

If you're referring to letter casing and such you could easily fix that in your own code.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to query the data on a regular basis and store it as a table. This way you will be able to find information about a query. I can be done by querying data from cloud trail and storing it as a table, or using the query history API like you mentioned.
Here is a solution which includes both cloud-trail and/or athena API. Joining the two sources give you the user, query and data scanned:

https://www.imperva.com/blog/how-to-monitor-athena-usage-to-understand-your-operations-and-control-security-and-costs/

There are code snippets inside